# enabling lazy load for angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

```
<div class="flex-container-new">

    <div class="header-alert-gauges">
        <div style="margin: 0px 2px 0px 26px;">
            <dashboard-header></dashboard-header>
        </div>
        <div class="alret-container" style="margin:25px 5px 2px 26px;">
             **<dashboard-body></dashboard-body>**
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-aside-MFN">
        <dashboard-aside class="dashboard-aside-flex-container"></dashboard-aside>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I make dashboard-body lazy load, can some some share the sample code or any link available where I can refer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to the following post.

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/lazy-load-components-in-angular-596357ab05d8

But it's a little bit complicated. So you can rather use `ngIf` and implement a conditional rendering with some boolean variable.